# SSO Auto login spring application against OIF

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, autologin

I've a web application with spring security SAML filters. I want to log into an external(partner) site and perform a few selections and return result back to my web application.  The partner has SSO set up with Oracle Identity Federation.  Is it possible to set up auto login to partners site using SSO? 
User clicks for resource x -> My site does auto log in and redirects to partner site.
Thank you

Comment: try adding code you already tried and what errors you're getting

Comment: The partner  has given me credentials to log in, which I need to integrate with my application. I do not know how to feed those credentials to do the auto login.  Right now the user gets partner login page.